# Switching XML Layouts in Android with Radio Button

Tags: android, xml, layout, radio-button

i have apk where on start i show one layout and on the top of is radio buttonst which should on check change layout its something like on start is shown layout PC and on click it should change to Playstation or Xbox

in the evening i will post source code, but now how to make it work ? i found few solutions but nothing work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create new actitivies for different layout files? However try this maybe it will help you.

CB_Event.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {

            if (isChecked) {

                setContentView(R.layout.YOURfirstLayout);

            } else {

                setContentView(R.layout.YOURSecondLayout);
            }

        }
    });
```

In this example i used CheckBox you can use RadioButton too.